# Getting stuck in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, random

So I have an Array with 100 int elements, that have to be drawn randomly within the range [-100,100], and has to return the amount of numbers that are odd and are within this range [-30,30]. And I do this:

```
int counter = 0;
int i = 0;
int[] numbers = new int[100];
for ( i = 0; i <= numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    numbers[i] = rnd.Next(-100, 101);
    if (numbers[i] % 2 != 0)
    {
        if (numbers[i] >= -30 && numbers[i] <= 30)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

And I build and receive no errors. But when running I receive this error on the command prompt: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Then it guides me to this line:

```
numbers[i]=rnd.Next(-100,101);
```

So, like, what's happening? What is the wrong thing I did?

Comment: change your for condition from i <= numbers.Length to i < numbers.Length.
Remember that your array index are from 0 to length -1

Comment: You'll also want to move the `Random rnd = new Random();` outside of the loop to prevent getting the same value on more than one iteration as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005230/method-displays-incorrect-results/26005673#26005673).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `<=` with `<` in the for-loop. So

```
for ( i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
```

instead of

```
for ( i = 0; i <= numbers.Length; i++)
```

collections are zero based in .NET. So you find the first item at 0 and the last at  index 99.

---

You should also move the `Random` initialization outside of the loop:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for ( i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    // Random rnd = new Random();  <--- No, no!
```

Because the [default constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the current time as seed for the `Random`. When you use the same seed you will always generate the same sequence. Since the loop is executed too fast the same seed is used.

Quote:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in
>   close succession by a call to the default constructor will have
>   identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical
>   sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single
>   Random object to generate all random numbers

Comment: Okay thanks for that. But now the "counter" returns 0. And when i put it in the for loop, it goes like 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 etc. etc. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @AlexanderPierce - see my comment on your question for that.

Comment: @AlexanderPierce: i have also added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

your array is iterating from 0 to 100

use:

```
for ( i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
```